# Questions about USB graphics cards

Tags: usb, graphics-card

I've been thinking about buying a high-end ultabook, but since I'm a PC gamer, I'm worried about the performance. I've heard of USB graphic cards, but I'm unsure how well those perform.

If I buy an ultabook with USB3 ports and a external graphics card dock that supports USB3, will it be just as fast as if it where in my computer?

Comment: A USB3 graphics card are several times slower then a grahic card connect to a PCIEx16 bus.

Comment: Interesting. That's kind of what I figured. What about something like Firewire or Thunderbolt (although I don't think Thunderbolt is available on a Windows machine)?

Comment: Firewire is several times slower then USB3.  If you are able to afford an external Thunderbolt you might as well just purchase a ultrabook with a highend mobile graphics card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've been thinking about buying a high-end ultrabook, but since I'm a PC gamer, 
>   I am worried about the performance. I've heard of USB graphic cards, but I am
>   unsure how well those perform.

This depends on the graphics card, but the performance usually is a lot slower than those of a regular PCI-e graphics card.

Basically you have the following options:

1. Build in graphics, e.g. in the APU, on the CPU die or via a dedicated graphics chip.
   This will work, but it will use a lot of power which is not compatible with the ultrabook (thin, very long battery life and low power parts).
2. An external graphics card via USB 2:  This will be slow.
3. An external graphics card via USB 3:  This should work. Not sure if it works well enough for gaming.
4. An external graphics card via [thunderbolt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)). This should work almost as well as a normal graphics card in a desktop because it will use a normal desktop graphics card. You usually only get an x4 or an x8 [PCI-e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCIe) connection (depending on the thunderbolt chip used) which will slow down graphics by a few percent.  (How much depends per game, but 4% is a good guess).
5. An external graphics card via the [express card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express_card) slot. Basically express card is USB plus a single PCI-e lane.  Either with a very small card in the expresscard slot, or [with a normal PCI-e graphics card and a convertor](http://forum.notebookreview.com/e-gpu-external-graphics-discussion/418851-diy-egpu-experiences.html#introduction).
6. Via a free mini PCI-e slot on the notebook. Assuming your BIOS supports it (a laptop BIOS's often does not) and assuming you have a free connector (also unlikely in an ultrabook where space is at a premium).
7. A laptop with a docking station and either a free PCI-e slot in the dock of a build in graphics card in the dock.  (Similar to the large docks of the Dell lattitude D-series).

Answer (score 0):

USB3 is as fast as Thunderbolt when only one card is used.....don't confuse USB2 with USB3.....also Firewire is as slow as USB2, so again, the most economical solution is a USB3 solution. Only problem is I havent' seen many such solutions that take advantage of the USB3 speeds.

Comment: This answer is just wrong: USB 3.0 offers about 4Gbit/s in total, Thunderbolt 10Gbit/s in each direction, the next iteration will even have 20Gbit/s. Thunderbolt actually is a native PCIe connection, where USB-graphic cards have much more protocol levels in-between slowing things down and requiring the CPU to do more work.